# Variable mass systems

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, rocket-science, variable-mass-systems

I'm studying this article:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec14.pdf

and I have the following doubt:

On page 3, when he derives the equation of motion (11), he says that the external forces $\mathbf{F}$ acts only on $m$, and not also on $dm$ (see equation (9)). Why? If we think that $\mathbf{F}$ is the gravity force (as he does in the following pages in the Rocket example), then why $dm$ does not feel gravity?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the force $\vec{F}$ is proportional to the mass of the system: most often, it is the gravitational force $\vec{F}=m\vec{g}$ and therefore on the mass $dm$, $\vec{dF}=dm\vec{g}$ which leads to a second order term, in $dmdt$, for the impulse.

Answer (score 0):

The reaction force on the rocket engine depends on the change in momentum of dm which is caused by the engine, but not that caused by gravity.